# C++ return new instance of object from dictionary

Tags: c++

How to achieve something like this in C++? I'd like some method to return instances of object based on provided string. I suspect `map` might be solution but I don't know how to pass method to it?

```
class Container {
  dictionary = {
    A: () => new A(),
    B: () => new B(),
    C: () => new C(),
  };

  method(choice: string): Parent {
    return this.dictionary[choice];
  }
}

class Parent {}

class A extends Parent {}

class B extends Parent {}

class C extends Parent {}
```

Comment: `std::map<std::string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<Parent>()>>`?

Comment: Implement a Factory pattern

Comment: @Jarod42 Do you mean to create a factory which contains method returning certain object for every object type. And then create map which contains strings as keys and factory methods as values?

Comment: That could work. Using a simple if-else would work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can propose the following solution:

a base class:

```cpp
class Base {
}
```

a factory singleton:

```cpp
class Factory
{
public:
    static Factory &instance()
    {
        static Factory inst;
        return inst;
    }
    bool Register(const std::string &name, CreateCallback funcCreate)
    {
        m_classes.insert(std::make_pair(name, funcCreate));    
    }
    Base* CreateInstance(const std::string &name)
    {
        auto it = m_classes.find(name);
        if(it != m_classes.end())
        {
            return it->second();
        }

    return nullptr;
    }

private:
    using CreateCallback = Base *(*)();
    std::map<std::string, CreateCallback> m_classes;
}

#define CLASS_IMPL(T) Base *T::CreateMethod() { return new T(); }

#define REGISTER_CLASS(T,N) bool T::m_registered = Factory::instance().Register(N, &T::CreateMethod);\
CLASS_IMPL(T)

#define CLASS_DECL protected: \
static Base *CreateMethod(); \
static bool m_registered; \
```

usage:
class declaration:

```cpp
class A: public Base
{
CLASS_DECL
public:
    A(){}
}
```

class definition:

```cpp
REGISTER_CLASS(A, "A");
A::A() : Base()
{
}
```

create other classes in such manner.

usage:

```cpp
Base* a = Factory::Instance().CreateInstance("A");
```

This is Factory implementation and so a kind of a "self registration" pattern.

Comment: Prefer to return smart_pointer over raw owning pointer.

Comment: @Jarod42, sure it's a matter of personal preference. As for me, I work with limited Linux embedded systems, very limited in memory, CPU etc. and so I prefer raw pointer since shared_ptr adds several function calls, you know ... get() etc.  that can be critical in a specified case.

Comment: I though about `std::unique_ptr`. chance are that `get` would be inlined anyway.